# How to bundle single file with webpack, without module runtime?

Tags: webpack

I have project with react.js and typescript which compiled it in two chunks: `app.bundle.js`(app code), `vendor.bundle.js` (libraries) with following webpack config:

```
{
  entry: {
    app: ['/src/app.tsx'],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', <...>]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve('./build')
  },
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js', Infinity),
    ...
  ]
}
```

I need to bundle `sw.ts` file separately, without webpack runtime. How can i do this? Adding as one more common chunk provides an error, moving sw.ts to the entry point makes it with `webpackJsonp` function, but i nedd just to trinspile from ts to js.